# .Net Core 3 and Angular without HTTPS?

Tags: angular, .net-core

sorry if this seems a bit odd. I'd like to be able to run an internal customer service web using Core 3 and Angular without using HTTPS. I know I can get it to work if I enable HTTPS locally. I just wonder if this is something hardcoded into the Identity framework.

if I remove the `UseHttpsRedirection()` from the Startup I get token issue failures. I'm just green enough in this environment to feel like some of you know whats going on. I am guessing the Angular app is expecting the HTTPS somewhere but I am just starting to look around here and would appreciate any direction

```
IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService: Information: {
  "Name": "Token Issued Failure",
  "Category": "Token",
  "EventType": "Failure",
  ///partial just to show error
}
```

Comment: Is it an Angular CLI project or is it built from the .Net Core project template?

Comment: . Net Core Project, thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Although I see some CLI projects coming at me as well, so I wouldn't mind an answer for both if you have it